# What can I do with my XML documentation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, documentation

I just discover I can generate XML documentation for my project with VisualStudio 2010 with the '///' tags in the code.. It's seems magical but what can I do with that? 
Is some application exists who can make me a "beautiful doc" with the XML file? Or convert it into a HTML doc?

Thanks a lot for all responses!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several apps out there that can take your XML Comments and generate MSDN Style API docs for you (working on the list):

[Sandcastle (Microsoft)](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/)
[NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/)
[Live Documenter](http://theboxsoftware.com/products/live-documenter/)

Comment: +1 for Sandcastle, but I think NDoc is dead (last version is from 2005) and Sandcastle is its replacement.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try Sandcastle then..

Comment: Apparently, Sandcastle itself [lost microsoft's support](https://sandcastle.codeplex.com/discussions/398496) recently, but the [Sandcastle Help File Builder](https://shfb.codeplex.com/) project is still alive and has taken over Sandcastle code.

Comment: Kaspersky AV flags the "sandcastle.codeplex.com/" link as having a virus or malware. 

Answer (score 1):

I use [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) to help generate the xml doc comments, and [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) with [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) to turn that into a compiled help file, which looks similar to the MSDN documentation.

You can find a detailed guide to using Sandcastle/Sandcastle Help File Builder [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/taming-sandcastle-a-.net-programmers-guide-to-documenting-your-code/).

I also tried [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) and found it to be fairly easy to use, but preferred the look of the documentation that Sandcastle produced.

Comment: The problem with doxygen is it uses a different format for documentation than the VS IDE does, meaning you won't get any info in intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative tool [DocFX](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/index.html) developed by Microsoft.

It generates API doc in HTML format like [this](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/api/Microsoft.DocAsCode.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another application: [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html)