# Generate documentation from C# class library

Tags: c#, documentation, documentation-generation

I have developed a C# class library which contains numerous projects. I am using this as a common library across multiple different projects.

A number of different developers have recently joined the team and not being familiar with the library they are not sure what is contained with it. I have it well commented with the help of ghostdoc.

Is it possible to auto generate documentation using any tool of the library? I would like to run a tool against it that would generate documentation for me that I could make the developers aware of to read. I presume such a tool would generate the documentation from the comments.

Comment: look these questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641364/c-sharp-documentation-generator/641402#641402 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665925/what-are-some-good-net-code-documentation-tools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend using [Sandcasle Help File Builder](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB) to generate documentation from your source code. You will want to review [XML Documentation Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) as the quality and robustness of your generated documentation is directly related to the richness of the XML comments you use.

SHFB can generate HTML and/or compiled help documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Visual Studio go to the projects' properties, select Build, then uner Ouput tick the XML documentation file checkbox.

Comment: Yes I am using VS, what will this output?

Comment: It will generate the XML documentation file for the project (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx#id0400045). Based on your question I think you want human readable documentation like you see on MSDN. Sandcastle consumes this XML documentation to generate human readable documentation.

Comment: Here's an example of code & the related generated xml: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z04awywx.aspx  To make the XML more readable you could then apply an XSL stylesheet or could use one of a number of tools (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304780/what-can-i-do-with-my-xml-documentation).

Answer (score 1):

I've recently made a simple to use library that generates markdown documentation from C# code. All it takes is a class library dll file. 
If you want to give it a try, [here's a link](https://github.com/CBinet/AutoDocumentation) on how to start using it with examples of generated documentation.

More informations : https://www.nuget.org/packages/BetaSoftware.AutoDocumentation

Comment: 404 Not Found on both links!

Comment: I made the repository public again. Thanks @DanielWilliams